# Git: Permission denied on file that was too big to stash

Tags: git

Earlier today I created a stash for some changes I didn't want to commit just yet. The stash consisted of an update of an external library we use (Telerik ASP.Net Ajax). When creating the stash (through Sourcetree) I got an error message saying that one file (Telerik.Web.UI.xml) was too big to stash, however, the stash was still created (I assume without this big file).

When I now run "git status" in the terminal I get:

```
externals/Telerik.Web.UI.xml: Permission denied
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

However, if I now try to apply my stash I get:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    externals/Telerik.Web.UI.xml
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.

Aborting
```

What should I do to resolve this lock that has happened with Telerik.Web.UI.xml? I can also not delete the file through windows explorer.

I've also tried to do a hard reset, but then I get:

```
error: unable to create file externals/Telerik.Web.UI.xml (Permission denied)
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'HEAD'.
```

How can I just reset this file to what it was before I updated it?

Answer (score 1):

It was Visual Studio and not GIT that was locking the file. After closing the project in Visual Studio I could handle the situation.